# Running Gunicorn with Foreman

Tags: django, gunicorn, foreman

If I do `runserver` or `gunicorn` straight from the commandline, the website works fine. However, if I try to run gunicorn using Foreman as specified in the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django):

```
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi
```

Then my website's static files are suddenly inaccessible; trying to go to

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

Only gives me this error message:

```
Using the URLconf defined in myapp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^$ [name='homepage']
    ...

The current URL, static/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

As I've said, the static files are definitely accessible if calling gunicorn or runserver directly, or even if using `runserver` with `foreman start`, so I'm guessing it doesn't have too much to do with my static files settings?

Also, running gunicorn on foreman with `DEBUG = False` doesn't even return anything except for a 500 error. Nothing is logged, not even on Sentry, so I have no idea what's wrong. It also works fine using gunicorn or runserver alone, or using runserver with foreman.

Any ideas what I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about why the static files were not being retrieved, but the `DEBUG = False` 500 error was simply caused by my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting, and fixing that produced no further issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to print out settings while running under gunicorn and see if your media URL is correct and js files are indeed accessible.

As for 500 error it is probably trying to show you 404 page, but you do not have a template for it, so it raises 500, and old django quirk ;)

PS. This all is assuming that you verified that you have correct URL pattern in that error

Comment: Thanks for the guess, but well, I don't have any user-uploaded files, so my media url is empty and unused. My static url is definitely working, at least when running gunicorn directly. As I said, js files are inaccessible when running gunicorn from foreman, but accessible when running gunicorn directly. And the 500 error shows even on the homepage, so I am pretty sure it is not a 404 error...